# Selenium Java - wait.until(ExpectedConditions is working at non-headless mode but not at headless mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, headless

At Selenium with Java I have this line:

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Return to:')]")));

which works fine at non-headless mode, but not working at headless mode.
I get the error "Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by... : Return to:".

I use Selenium 3.141.5 with chromedriver 101.0.4951.41.

What could be the reason? I have also tried to find element by linkText.

Comment: I've experienced same issue. The element your are waiting for is already visible. The expected condition has to be false to avoid the exception. You can go around with `if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Return to:')]")).size() = 0) { your wait here}`